# Using Hashmaps with Scanner() function

Tags: java

The following code is my attempt at a hashmap that works as a phonebook.  There are names and phone numbers, and if you enter a name that is not in the directory, the code returns "Not found".

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap.*;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            String name = sc.next();
            int phone = sc.nextInt();
            HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        }

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String name = sc.next();
            int phone = sc.nextInt();
            if(hmap.containsKey(sc.next())){
                System.out.println(name + "=" + phone);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the program, I get a runtime error: ~ no response on stdout ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet

```java
            String name = sc.next();
            int phone = sc.nextInt();
            if(hmap.containsKey(sc.next())){
```

advances the scanner twice (actually three times). So the key which is checked is not the name, but the part after the phone number. Change to `if(hmap.containsKey(name))`, since you already scanned and the name from the input and stored it into the variable. Everytime you call `sc.next()` the scanner is advanced and it consumes one token of the input. If you want to re-use values, you have to store them in a variable and then reference that variable.

Not sure why your input contains the phone number too, if you only want to lookup by name?